# Needing a double inclusion to determine the kernel of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be an endomorphism of $\mathbb R^3$ whose matrix relatively to the canonical basis is given by:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 &2\\ -2 &5 &3 \\ 2& -4 &-2 \end{pmatrix}$$

I want to determine $\ker f$ and give it a basis. I read on a book the following answer : Take $(x,y,z)\in \ker f$ then $(x,y,z)=x(1,1,-1)$ hence $\ker f= \operatorname {span}((1,1,-1))$. My problem is that the answer just proves $\ker f\subset \operatorname {span}((1,1,-1))$  and we need to check that $\operatorname {span}((1,1,-1))\subset \ker f$  which is not hard to check but i need to know if that step is necessary or there is an argument that makes this step not necessary.

Comment: You may use a rank / dimension argument to conclude?

Comment: Do you know what is the ker of a linear transformation? Wat is his definition?

Comment: @AlexHalm  If we know that dimension of $\ker f$ is one then it's ok we don't need the other inclusion but here we don't seem to know the dimension of $\ker f$, aren't we ?

Comment: Not a priori. But in case you knew something else on rank $f$ (which we already know is 1 or 2) you could use the codim of rank and ker.

Comment: So you agree that we need the other inclusion and  what we have by that computation is just the inclusion of the kernel in the span and it is not an equality ?